# Suspending a process and resume after a system shutdown/reboot

Tags: shutdown, reboot, process, kill

Under Ubuntu you can suspend a process by

```
kill -STOP [process ID]
```

and resume by

```
kill -CONT [process ID]
```

But my question is, does this also work after a full system shutdown/reboot ? Will the process ID be stored on the machine (and not overwritten by a new process)?

Or are there any other alternatives available?

Many thanks in advance,

-- Stan

Comment: No, it doesn't work after a reboot, the PIDs are not stored on the machine, they are re-used after a reboot. I don't think you can suspend/resume a single process. You could suspend/resume (hibernate) the whole machine, or you could use a Virtual Machine like VirtualBox, but that's certainly a lot more expensive.

Comment: Please consider posting your comment as the answer for the question.

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer(s) to your question when possible (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Comment: Essentially, what this question asks for is hibernation, except it's saving state for all processes, not just a single one like in `kill -STOP` example.

Answer (score 4):

> does this also work after a full system shutdown/reboot?

- No.

> Will the process ID be stored on the machine (and not overwritten by a new process)?

- No. PIDs do not persist across reboots.

> Or are there any other alternatives available?

- Hibernation, which preserves the entire system state.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to checkpoint and restore the process. There are a lot of different [implementations](https://checkpointing.org/) of this feature, and not all of them work in all situations.  [CRIU](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2455211) (Checkpoint and Restore In Userspace) seems to be the most active and supported of the solutions ([official site](https://criu.org/Main_Page)). There's also [DMTCP](http://dmtcp.sourceforge.net/), which appears to be a mature solution and might work for you.

Another common solution is to run the program in a virtual machine which can be hibernated and restored.